# 'GOOS' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, go, webassembly

I'm trying to compile go to js/wasm like this (in the command line):

`GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o  ../../assets/json.wasm`

However, the response is as such:

```
'GOOS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I was following this guide: https://golangbot.com/webassembly-using-go/

Is there something I'm doing wrong? My platform is windows 10 and I'm running on Go version go1.19 windows/amd64. I really appreciate any support.

Comment: That looks like a command for a Unix shell, not Windows.

Comment: I think `set GOOS=js&& set GOARCH=wasm&& go build -o  ../../assets/json.wasm` should work?

Answer (score 3):

If you are on `Windows 10` using `PowerShell`, for that line of the tutorial you need to run:

```
$> $Env:GOOS = "js"; $Env:GOARCH = "wasm"; go build -o  ../../assets/json.wasm
```

**Note:** If you compile the `json.wasm` binary with the wrong parameters, in your web browser, when you test, you will get a weird error that looks likes:

```
caught (in promise) CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(): expected magic word 00 61 73 6d, found 4d 5a 90 00 @+0 Promise.then (async) (anonymous
```

But if you have compiled with the correct `GOOS` and `GOARCH` parameters, then you'll succeed:

[image]

**Finally:** One annoying thing is I had to was open ***two*** `PowerShell` windows because I was only able to set environment vars at the shell level. So running my `Go` server no longer worked after I'd set `$Env:GOOS = "js"; $Env:GOARCH = "wasm";` in that `PowerShell` instance.

**In summary:** Use one `PowerShell` instance to compile your `WASM` binaries and use another `PowerShell` instance to run your `Go` webserver.

Answer (score 1):

GOOS and GOARCH are environment variables.  Many Unix shells allow you to set environment variables at the start of the command line that just apply to the the rest of the command line.

But on Windows the left-most part of the command line must always be the program name so the above command line will not work on Windows.  The error message tells you that Windows is trying to run a program called "GOOS".

You should probably run a Unix shell on Windows.  (I use git-bash.)  If you want to use the Windows command prompt you can set the environment variables first like this:

```
> set GOOS=js
> set GOARCH=wasm
> go build -o  ..\..\assets\json.wasm
```

Note that GOOS and GOARCH will stay set to those values in the shell until you close it.

Comment: This didn't work for me when I used `PowerShell` on `Windows 10`.  I posted another answer above ^^.  What worked for me was running:`$> $Env:GOOS = "js"; $Env:GOARCH = "wasm"; go build -o  ../../assets/json.wasm`